# CakePHP .htaccess settings and shared ssl certificate

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, ssl

My shared host offers shared SSl certificate like the following:

```
https://host###.HostMonster.com/~username
```

Where host### is the hosting server for my account there.

I use CakePHP app on the root of `public_html` where I have `public_html/webroot` path and I use the following `.htaccess` settings on `public_html`:

```
# Turn off the ETags
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

# Turn off the Last Modified header except for html docs
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|mp3)$">
Header unset Last-Modified
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|mp3)$">
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Jan 2015 20:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|mp3)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31449600"
 </FilesMatch>

# Use PHP5.3 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

Redirect /Hosting/Q/ http://sub.mydomain.net/

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
   #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
   #RewriteBase /~twoindex/
   RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
AddType audio/mpeg mp3
AddType text/xml xml
```

When I try to access `https://host15.HostMonster.com/~myuser` where host15 is my host server, I got 404 error.

**I tried the following**:

- Creating a simple html file and placing it on `public_html` and then accessing it using `https://host15.HostMonster.com/~myuser/simple.html`. It also returns 404 error.
- I tried to comment out the two lines after  `RewriteEngine on` but no success too.
- Removing the contents of the `.htaccess` file i.e making it empty, allowed me to access `simple.html` via `https` successfully.

The last try, is not a real option for me because it will destroy my CakePHP application. However, it approved that it is a problem related with rewriting rules in the `.htaccess`. So, **I need to know** how to modify the `.htaccess` to allow accessing my CakePHP application while allowing accessing the `simple.html` or better a sub directory on `public_html`

### Update

I tried the following rule, but it ended with the error **`This webpage has a redirect loop`** when I try to access `https://host15.HostMonster.com/~myuser/folder` and it keeps everything fine for the CakePHP application.:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^host15\.HostMonster\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~myuser/$1 [R,L]

   RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
  </IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you access your app over insecure HTTP?

Comment: @Choma Yes I can. via `http://example.com`